# Convert array to ojbect with with key

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have a requirement to convert an array in to object with a key value. I have tried some code. But not getting exact result. Can i do it using lodash or underscore js?

```
array = [
    {
        facebook: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    },
    {
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
        twitter: 'disneyland',
    },
    {
       preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
        linkedin: 'disneyland',
    },
    {
        xing: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: ''
    },
    {
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png',
        weibo: 'disneyland'
    } 
]
```

expected output

```
result = {
    facebook: {
        facebook: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    },
    twitter: {
        twitter: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    },
    linkedin: {
        linkedin: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    },
    xing: {
        linkedin: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    },
    weibo: {
        linkedin: 'disneyland',
        preview_image_url: 'http: //amt.in/img/amt_logo_big.png'
    }
}
```

I have tried this

```
var newnwcontent = {};
array.forEach(function (network) {
                                var name = Object.keys(network)[0];
                                newnwcontent[name] = network;
                            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the property keys, index `0` is not guaranteed

```
var newnwcontent = {}

array.forEach(function(el) {
  var keys = Object.keys(el)
  var key = keys[0] == 'preview_image_url' ? keys[1] : keys[0]
  newnwcontent[key] = el
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approach in lodash:

```
_.indexBy(array, function(item) {
    return _(item)
        .keys()
        .without('preview_image_url')
        .first();
});
```

Here, [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) returns a new object based on an array. The function you pass it, tells it how to construct the keys. In this case, you use [keys()](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) to get the keys, [without()](https://lodash.com/docs#without) to remove what you don't need, and [first()](https://lodash.com/docs#first) to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such function to get the result that you need:

```
var result = {};
// iterate through all networks
array.forEach(function (network) {
    // iterate through all properties of an array item
    for(var property in network){
        // ignore property preview_image_url
        if(property!=='preview_image_url')
        {
            // any other property is your key, add an item to result object
            result[property] = network;
        }
    }
});
// output the result
console.log(result);
```